# document.elementFromPoint.click not work chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, click, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

How can i simulate click to make move with mouse in website
https://www.playok.com/p/?g=sc+

```
document.elementFromPoint(x,y).click();
```

It only works on some elements, but not in game board

Answer (score 0):

Your Dom Element - what you get with `elementFromPoint` - is the canvas element. And you are click on it, if you add Click event listener directly to the canvas element itself you will see it is ruing.

Comment: So, what i should do?